# Tensorflow: Is it normal that my GPU is using all its Memory but is not under full load?

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to run a text-based sequence to sequence model using tensorflow 2.6 and CuDNN.

The code is running, but taking suspiciously long. When I check my Task Manager, I see the following:

[image: Task Manager Screenshot]

This looks weird to me, because all memory is taking but it's not under heavy load.
Is this expected behaviour?

System:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.9
- Tensorflow & Keras 2.6
- CUDA 11.6
- CuDNN 8.3
- NVidia RTX 3080ti

In the code I found the following settings for the GPU

```
def get_gpu_config():
  gconfig = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
  gconfig.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.975 # Don't take 100% of the memory
  gconfig.allow_soft_placement = True # Does not aggressively take all the GPU memory
  gconfig.gpu_options.allow_growth = True # Take more memory when necessary
  return gconfig
```

My python output tells me it found my graphics card:

[image: Python Console]

And it is also visible in my `nvidia-smi` output:
[image: nvidia-smi output]

Am I maybe missing a configuration?
The times it takes are similar to what I got on a CPU system, which seems off to me.

Sidenote:

The [Code I try to run](https://github.com/mast-group/OpenVocabCodeNLM) had to be migrated from tensorflow-gpu 1.12, but that went "relatively" smooth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes this behaviour is normal for TensorFlow!

From the [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)

> By default, TensorFlow maps nearly all of the GPU memory of all GPUs (subject to CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES) visible to the process. This is done to more efficiently use the relatively precious GPU memory resources on the devices by reducing memory fragmentation. To limit TensorFlow to a specific set of GPUs, use the [tf.config.set_visible_devices](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_visible_devices) method.

---

If you don't want TensorFlow to allocate the totality of your VRAM, you can either set a hard limit on how much memory to use or tell TensorFlow to only allocate as much memory as needed.

#### To set a hard limit

Configure a virtual GPU device as follows:

```py
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.set_logical_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

#### Only use as much as needed

- You can set the environment variable `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true`

OR

- Use `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth` as follows:

```py
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

All code and information here is taken from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you imply that the GPU usage looks correct? 
I do not mind if it takes all my memory, but I am fearing that it's not really utilizing all of the GPU except for allocating the memory

Comment: It looks correct for a small model doing inference. To be sure the model is working correctly, I would check that, for the same input, both the original model and the one you ported give the same outputs